# New Relic: Slow queries with actual query with the values not showing in Database section

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, newrelic, newrelic-platform, kinto

I am new to New Relic and trying to explore the slow queries.

I integrated the new relic with the kinto.ini with postgres db.

Please see the highlighted section of screen-shot.

I set the "transaction_tracer.record_sql = raw" still not getting the sql queries with actual parameters.

**Question**: New relic gives me the list of slow queries but the *"actual query with the values not showing"*.

**[image: so is there any way other way to view actual query with parameters ?]**